# Drag 2 Google Maps Markers at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, lodash

I found a few articles online and a few posts on stack overflow that explain how to select multiple markers, but I have not been able to find anything that works for dragging 2 markers at the same time. I've been able to make it work in a way that allows 1 marker to fire an event on it's sibling and drag the related marker, but somehow it stops the dragging event on the marker that I clicked on.

I can't use complex polygons because it's not possible to change the color of only one path on a complex marker svg. I have to create 2 svgs, one for the center fill and the other for the outer fill and then I have to change the color of the outer fill.

This is how that works.

First I create the markers and then place them in the same location.

Then I pass those markers into this function.

```
addMultiMarkerListener:function(id, outer, inner){
    var arr = ['mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click','mouseover','mouseout', 'dragend','drag','dragstar'];
    var evtArr = {}
        _.each(arr, function(evt){
            evtArr[evt] = {};
            evtArr[evt][id] = false;

            outer.addListener(evt, function(){
                if(!evtArr[evt][id]){
                    evtArr[evt][id] = true;
                    google.maps.event.trigger(inner, evt);
                    evtArr[evt][id] = false

                }

            })

            inner.addListener(evt, function(){
                 if(!evtArr[evt][id]){
                    evtArr[evt][id] = true;
                    google.maps.event.trigger(outer, evt);
                    evtArr[evt][id] = false
                }
            })
        })

    },
```

I want this to be able to trigger the mousedown event for both markers so that when I click down, I can drag both of these markers at the same time. The way it works now, stops the first mousedown event when I fire the mousedown event on the sibling marker.

I was also thinking that I could fire a separate event that wouldn't interfere with the first. It might take a little bit of deep thought, but I think I can make it work. I was just hoping that someone else might be able to provide some insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Instead of firing two mousedown events I decided to get the position of the first marker on the drag event, and then set the position of the 2nd marker to the position of the first. Like so.

```
  addDragListener: function(marker, id, centerMarker) {
        var self = this;
        var fill = centerMarker;


        marker.addListener('drag', function(){
            var position = marker.getPosition();
            fill.setPosition(position);

        })
  }
```